# Alternative to pandas groupby with lambda and diff

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda, pandas-groupby

Assume I have `df` below:

```
    ID  V
0   A   1
1   A   2
2   B   4
3   B   3
```

And the desired output is:

```
    V
0   NaN
1   1.0
2   NaN
3   -1.0
```

This can be done using `groupby` and `lambda` with `diff`:

```
df.groupby('ID').apply(lambda x: x.diff())
```

I am trying to come up with a solution that doesn't rely on `lambda` as this quickly becomes very slow. Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

Performance comparison between (1) using `groupby`, `lambda` and `diff`, and, (2) only using `groupby` and `diff`:

1

```
3.67 ms ± 238 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

2

```
2.42 ms ± 20.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: What leads you to believe it would be slow?

Comment: Experience from applying it on large dataframes.

Comment: What makes you think the lambda is the result of the slowness I should say?

Comment: Just hypothesizing that, with a large number of groups, this becomes like applying `diff` way too many times and decreases performance. But you're right, maybe `lambda` isn't the issue. What's your intuition?

Comment: diff has to run once per group no matter how you do it, so the lambda vs calling .diff directly shouldn't matter much at all.

Comment: groupby + lambda + diff: `3.67 ms ± 238 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each).`. groupby + diff: `2.42 ms ± 20.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)`.

Comment: Those are both very fast, if you're feeling like either is too slow it may be a hardware limitation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, in this case, groupby objects directly support `diff`:

```
>>> df
  ID  V
0  A  1
1  A  2
2  B  4
3  B  3
>>> df.groupby('ID').diff()
     V
0  NaN
1  1.0
2  NaN
3 -1.0
>>>
```

But I'm not sure if this will actually improve your performance. Using `.apply` on columns, i.e. across the first axis, shouldn't be slower than the above, it is basically equivalent (unlike `.apply`ing on the rows).

Answer (score 2):

Use `.agg` and pass `diff`

```
 df.groupby('ID')['V'].agg('diff')

0    NaN
1    1.0
2    NaN
3   -1.0
```